# Generate JSON files for language translation from po file without wp-cli i18n make-json

Tags: plugin-development, translation, localization

My plugin uses `wp_set_script_translations()` to load translations for JS as mentioned here https://make.wordpress.org/core/2018/11/09/new-javascript-i18n-support-in-wordpress/.

I understand that when translations for a locale is added translate.wordpress.org it will create the JSON files.

But, we have a lot of site owners wants to translate a few words and start using the plugin.
They can create .po and .mo files, but how they can create the JSON files without setting up wp-cli to use (`wp i18n make-json`).

Loco Translate plugin is not supporting JSON file generation.

I couldn't find any online sites supporting .po to .json(with below mentioned format) conversion.

Out put file should in `${domain}-${locale}-${handle}.json` or `${domain}-${locale}-${md5}.json` JED 1.x ( .json ) file format for each JS file that called with `wp_set_script_translations()`.